# Minkowski distance to separate two classes

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning

What Minkowski distance: $d_p(x,y) = (\sum^N_{n=1}|x_n-y_n|^p)^{1/p}$ is appropriate for separating two classes where class 1 is defined as a square and the second class is defined as all the points surrounding the square and why?